# Command failed unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: electron, yarnpkg

When I create a brand new create-react-app and run the command `yarn add electron --dev` I get the following error.

```
RequestError: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\my-stuff\create-react-test\node_modules\got\source\request-as-event-emitter.js:178:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit (C:\my-stuff\create-react-test\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\source\index.js:37:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
```

The same thing happens with npm and chocolatey and only with electron. This doesn't happen on other computers. I've completely uninstalled node and reinstalled it.

This happens after it finished downloading the module. It is making a `ClientRequest` to a location on my computer. I don't understand why.

I've searched the internet for days for a solution. I've found the `cnpm` solution and it does work, but I want my project to be restorable from the git repository using `npm install` or `yarn`. Right now it is not. I'd have to remove electron from my `package.json`, restore, add it back and call the `cnpm` command.

`npm config set strict-ssl false` <- This command does not help.

I've tried separately installing `got` and `@szmarczak\http-timer`. This did not help.

Comment: I don't know if it works in all cases, but running this command line prior to an npm install that was failing on "unable to get local issuer certificate" (due to z-scaler) worked for me:
> set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old question but if anyone is facing this issue try running `yarn config set enableStrictSsl false`

Comment: I see that answer everywhere. 1) It doesn't solve my original problem. 2) It is there for a reason. I recommend that no one does this, ever. Some say not to leave it like this, but lets face it you are going to leave it like this. Just dont!